# Microsoft Teams Bot Tab not loading after adding Content Security Header

Tags: tabs, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

We have developed a bot with microsoft teams. We have added a tab with the bot. We have added content security to the header and we have set Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com in the header as mentioned in the below url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/add-tab

After doing the above the frame page is not getting loaded. We are getting the below error

Refused to frame XXXX because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com

Please help in resolving the issue

Comment: Within your content page - make sure you have added reference to "Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK" 
Add this "microsoftTeams.initialize()"
Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: We tried adding microsoftTeams.initialize() but still getting he same error

Comment: Did you add "Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK"?